# lvalue required as unary '&' operand

Tags: c, linux, visual-c++, compilation

Problem while making a call to function as follows:

Function call:

```
Sbac_DecodeBin(pstSlice->pstBAC,&(UINT8)ui32Abs_Mvd_G_0[0],
pstSlice->pstCtxModel->aucABS_MVD_GREATER_0_1_FLAG,0,
pstSlice->pstValMps->aucABS_MVD_GREATER_0_1_FLAG,BSHandle);
```

Function declaration:

```
VOID Sbac_DecodeBin(Init_BAC *pstBAC,UINT8* piBinValue,UINT8* pucSateIdx,
UINT8 CtxInc,UINT8* pucValMPS,HEVCD_BS_HANDLE BSHandle)
```

The above code doesnt give any compilcation error in Visual c++ 2008 But in linux while creating object file using  makefile via `gcc -c` i get the error:

```
lvalue required as unary '&' operand
```

Can anyone tell me what is the problem?

Comment: The `&(UINT8)ui32Abs_Mvd_G_0[0]` looks odd. I am not sure I have seen ever seen code with casting between the `&` and its operand. What are you trying to do? Also, if it works on MSVC++, what is the outcome of that code?

Answer (score 5):

Change the second argument in the call from 
`&(UINT8)ui32Abs_Mvd_G_0[0]`to `(UINT8 *)ui32Abs_Mvd_G_0`.

The reason for the error message is that you can't take the address of something that isn't an lvalue. A cast from uint32 -> uint8 doesn't qualify. A cast from uint32* to uint8* does.

BTW: You are looking at a potential endianness goof. On little endian you are passing the address of the LSB of the uint32, on big endian you are passing the address of the MSB.

Comment: As a note: the original code works in MS C because "Microsoft C includes an extension to the ANSI C standard that allows casts of l-values to be used as l-values, as long as the size of the object is not lengthened through the cast: (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bkbs2cds.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

`UINT8` is non-standard. I guess it is a specific to the MSVC++ compiler. Try using `uint8_t` defined in `stdint.h` instead. Use `(uint8_t*)ui32Abs_Mvd_G_0[0]` to match the type.

**Edit** As per discussion in comments below, this should work `(UINT8*)ui32Abs_Mvd_G_0[0]`

Comment: UINT8 is defined by me in an included header file

Comment: But why are you casting it and then taking its address?

Comment: BCoz if u see the declaration the second argument is of type UINT8*

Comment: Take the address and cast that to a `UINT8*`